# Search User Information Across different Microsoft Tenants

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I want to be able to search for users across multiple tenants, and therefore my thoughts were to create a python script that runs on HTTP triggered Azure functions. This python script can authenticate to Microsoft Graph API for different tenants via service principals and then search for a user and return the data. is this a good idea or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I assume you wanna to achieve a funtion which calling `xxx.net?tenant=target_tenant&user=user_name` then it will return user information. Basically, if we need to gather user information via graph api, we need an azure ad app in that tenant and generate an access token by the app, with the token we can get user information. In your requirement, you wanna gather information in different tenant, so you need to create ad app(multiple tenant app if needed) in each tenant, and according to the request parameter to decide which app to use. Do I misunderstand in some place?

Comment: thats correct. for example we have a user called test and we want to find out information about this user, however we do not know which Tenant the user lives. Therefore we loop through each tenant using a script and then return the results..

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am really not familiar with python. If you have further questions, pls feel free to update here.

Comment: Can my post help you? Pls let me know if it works. And if you get any other solutions, you can also post here and mark it as the answer so that it may help others. Thanks in advance :）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's discuss on the achievement.

I find that one `multi-tenant` azure ad application is enough for querying users in different tenant through graph api. For example, there're 2 tenants, I created a multi-tenant application in azure ad app registration, after that I generated the client secret and add api permission of `User.Read.All`.

Now I have an app with its client id and secret in 'tenant_a'. Next, visit `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_b}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}` in the browser, after sign in with the admin account in tenant_b, it will appear a 'permission' window to make consent the application have permission in tenant_b, after the consent, you will the the app created in tenant_a appears in the list of `Enterprise applications` in tenant_b.

Now we need to generate access token for different tenant to call [graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request). It's necessary to generate access token for each tenant, because I tried to use `common` to replace the domain in the request(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`), it can generate access token successfully, but the token can't used in the api to query user information. The query user api needs user principal name as the input parameter. For example, I have a user which account is 'bob@tenant_b.onmicrosoft.com', use the account as the parameter is ok to get response, but if I use 'bob' as the parameter, it will return 'Resource xxx does not exist...'.

I'm not an expert in python, I only found a sample and tested successfully with it. Here's my code, it will execute loop query until the user be found. And if you wanna a function, you may create a http trigger base on it.

```
import sys
import json
import logging
import requests
import msal

config = json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))
authorityName = ["<tenant_a>.onmicrosoft.com","<tenant_b>.onmicrosoft.com"]
username = "userone@<tenant_a>.onmicrosoft.com"

for domainName in authorityName:
    # Create a preferably long-lived app instance which maintains a token cache.
    print("==============:"+config["authority"]+domainName)
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        "<client_id>", authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+domainName,
        client_credential="<client_secret>",
        )
        # The pattern to acquire a token looks like this.
    result = None

    # Firstly, looks up a token from cache
    # Since we are looking for token for the current app, NOT for an end user,
    # notice we give account parameter as None.
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"], account=None)

    if not result:
        result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])

    if "access_token" in result:
        print("access token===:"+result['access_token'])
        # Calling graph using the access token
        graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"+username,
            headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']}, ).json()
        if "error" in graph_data:
            print("error===="+json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
        else:
            print(json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
            break

    else:
        print(result.get("error"))
        print(result.get("error_description"))
        print(result.get("correlation_id"))
```

[image]